# Filter list of users based upon one of their parameter values in rails?

Tags: ruby

I am using the following gem: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails
I am trying to create @users inside my controller to only display users with the parameter "status" equal to "active"

```
def index
  @users = User.all
  @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@users) do |user, marker|
    marker.lat user.latitude
    marker.lng user.longitude
    marker.title user.title
    user_link = view_context.link_to user.title, user_path(user)
    marker.infowindow "<h4><u>#{user_link}</u></h4><i>#{user.address}</i>"
  end
end
```

In views/users/index.html.erb, I have a js function.

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
});
```

and in index.json.jbuilder I have:

```
json.array!(@users) do |user|
  json.extract! user, :id, :latitude, :longitude, :address, :status, :title
  json.url user_url(user, format: :json)
end
```

I have tried a few matching functions in my controller, but I am unsure of where to put the IF logic, ie. is it best suited to be in the index.json.jbuilder, the index.hmtl.erb or the controller?

Comment: Side note, I will pull the Gmaps4rails out to clean up the controller and help with testing and such.  Maybe service object called MapBuilder and then it takes in a user and marker.

Answer (score 1):

Probably best in the Model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.active
    where(status: true) 
  end

end
```

Then in your controller

```
@users = User.active
```

Comment: should I still be calling    User.all    ?

Comment: I cannot edit the above response due to the (IMO, ridiculous) rule that an edit cannot be less than 6 characters), but `@user` should be `@users` to match the OP's question

Comment: I tried adding the model and replace "@users = User.all" with "@users = User.active" and it did not work as planned.

Comment: What happened when you made the change?

Comment: No users appear on the map, map shows at 0,0. If I call @users = User.all everything works and I see all the users on the map. I can also see the users' status when viewing their show.html.erb, but I cannot seem to get this logic working properly for the map.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't add the active method to the user class.

Comment: Could you share this on github or give me read to the project and i'll just send you a pr.  github.com/Austio  The solution you posted 'works' but it isn't a best practice.